# How to initialize variables in parent abstract class of spring bean using Kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have the next structure of spring beans

```
abstract class GenericRepository<T> {

private val FIND_BY_ID_SQL = "SELECT * FROM ${this.getTableName()} WHERE id = ?"

abstract fun getTableName(): String

abstract fun jdbcTemplate(): JdbcTemplate

abstract fun getMapper(): RowMapper<T>

fun find(id: Long): T? {
    return jdbcTemplate().queryForObject(FIND_BY_ID_SQL, arrayOf(id), getMapper())
}
}
```

User repository

```
@Repository
class UserRepository(
    @Autowired
    private val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate
) : GenericRepository<User>() {

companion object {
    private const val INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO \"user\"(name, age) VALUES (?,?)"
}

private class LogMapper : RowMapper<User> {
    override fun mapRow(rs: ResultSet, rowNum: Int): User? {
        return User(
                id = rs.getLong("id"),
                name = rs.getString("name"),
                age = rs.getInt("operation")
        )
    }
}

override fun getTableName(): String {
    return "user"
}

override fun jdbcTemplate(): JdbcTemplate {
    return jdbcTemplate
}

override fun getMapper(): RowMapper<User> {
    return LogMapper()
}
}
```

The problem when Spring creates proxy and creates bean of UserRepository it doesn't initialize FIND_BY_ID_SQL leaving it null.

[image: Null variable]

The question: how usign abstract class make spring initialize FIND_BY_ID_SQL variable?

UPD

I used @Component instead of @Repository and the problem was solved. FIND_BY_ID_SQL is not null anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around the problem by making it [lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy):

```
private val FIND_BY_ID_SQL by lazy { "SELECT * FROM ${this.getTableName()} WHERE id = ?" }
```

However, you should first be sure it's an actual problem (e.g. that when you call `find` you get an exception), because the proxy might simply delegate to a "real" `UserRepository` with non-null `FIND_BY_ID_SQL` (and `jdbcTemplate` etc.), depending on Spring's internal details.

In addition, you need to be careful when your superclass properties are initialized depending on subclass; I think your exact situation should work, but I'd prefer to write it as

```
abstract class GenericRepository<T>(val tableName: String) {

    private val FIND_BY_ID_SQL = "SELECT * FROM ${tableName} WHERE id = ?"

    abstract val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate

    abstract val mapper: RowMapper<T>

    fun find(id: Long): T? {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(FIND_BY_ID_SQL, arrayOf(id), mapper)
    }
}

@Repository
class UserRepository(
    @Autowired
    override val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate
) : GenericRepository<User>("user") { ... }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, the idea behind Companion Object is to provide equivalents to Java's `static` elements. One could argue that repository's SQL statement makes little sense in absence of said repository's instance and doesn't have to or even shouldn't be statically visible.

Comment: Not trying to undermine you - here trying to learn more while sharing what I've already learned with other. Would you be kind to walk me through advantages of such declaration? What I am able to spot is: memory micromanagement - string is not duplicated per instance of repository; (arguably, again) elegance of having resource-type strings available statically. Are there other benefits to highlight? Then OTOH: `this` in the context of a `companion object` references only to the companion itself (there might be no instance) hence `getTableName()` of your example should be part of companion?

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I actually didn't notice it depends on `getTableName`, so the premise of my answer (that "it's the same for all instances") is wrong.

Comment: Gave a different answer.

Comment: @alexey-romanov The hack with lazy doesn't work here. I replaces "@Repository" with "@Component". Right now I am looking for an explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: I mention the likely explanation here: "because the proxy might simply delegate to a "real" UserRepository with non-null FIND_BY_ID_SQL (and jdbcTemplate etc.), depending on Spring's internal details" If so, you should be able to find the real `UserRepository` hiding under one of the `CGLIB$CALLBACK_*`s.